# Adding paragraphs to automated email

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have created a script that automatically sends out emails that pulls information from several cells and populates the body of the email with the information alongside a standard body of the text.

However I can't work out a way to script in a paragraph space between the lines. I have done a workaround of creating a variable with the value of a cell that is just a paragraph space but, as other people will be using this spreadsheet, I am worried that the cell will get deleted and the formatting will change.

Is there another way to format paragraphs into the body of the email?

See my code below if that helps! The variable I need to format is "Var Message"

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = 99;  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 16)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var EMAIL_SENT = "Contacted";
  var currentdate = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("n2").getValue(), "GMT" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );
  var staffmember = sheet.getRange("o2").getValue();
  var paragraph = sheet.getRange("f2").getValue(); 
  var row = data[i];
  var emailAddress = row[0];  
  var name = row[1];
  var company = row[2];
  var website = row[3];
  var role = row[4];
  var show = row[9];
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(row[15], "GMT" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );
  var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(row[15], "GMT" , "dd/MM" );
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(row[11], "GMT" , "HH:mm" );
  var message = "Hello," + paragraph + "Could you please authorise or decline the following Arts Industry comp request from the Fringe Office? If you could reply within 72 hours, that would be great:" + paragraph + name + "  " + company + "  " + website + "  " + role + paragraph + show + "  " + date + "  " + time + paragraph + "Many thanks," + paragraph + staffmember ;
  var subject = "ARTS INDUSTRY REQUEST";
  var emailSent = row[12];

if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
  if (date > currentdate) {
  var subject = "ARTS INDUSTRY REQUEST";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 13).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }

 else if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
  if (date < currentdate) {
  var subject2 = "URGENT: ARTS INDUSTRY REQUEST" + " " + date2;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject2, message);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 13).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }    
    }  
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plaintext emails, you can use the "newline" escape sequence `\n`.

If you have K&R "[C - The Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)", you'll find a full list of escape sequences in chapter 2. An online reference is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

```
var message = "Hello,\n"
            + "Could you please authorise or decline the following Arts Industry comp request from the Fringe Office? If you could reply within 72 hours, that would be great:\n\n" 
            + name + "  " + company + "  " + website + "  " + role
            + '\n' + show + "  " + date + "  " + time
            + '\n\n'
            + "Many thanks,"
            + '\n\n'
            + staffmember ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the advanced options of `MailApp.sendEmail()` function to achieve paragraph and line breaks more efficiently. Here is an example

```
var content = "Here is some text <br> " + 
   "that is split over two lines" ; 
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{'htmlBody' : content } );
```